# How to debug multi-thread deadlock in C++ Qt program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

for multi-thread deadlock bugs (or other multi-thread related bugs) which only happens very rarely and difficult to repeat, and when it happens the program freezes under windows so I could not even attach a debugger to it.
Some times the bug even only happens at some certain condition (like when the CPU is busy).
For these bugs, is there any magic software or techniques that could save my day?

EDIT:
Sorry for my not-so-specific question, I am just debugging a huge software with no single line of documentation written by others. So I just would like to know is there any thing like a code analyzer or any useful techinques that could quickly detect the multi-thread bugs?

Comment: First look at your lock/unlock orders.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and sorry for my not-so-specific question, I am just debugging a huge software with no single line of documentation written by others... So I just would like to know is there any thing like a code analyzer that could detect the multi-thread bugs?

Comment: Logging and more logging.  Once software has got into that state of intermittent multithreading bugs, they are very difficult to get out. You need ALL the help you can get to assemble evidence and narrow down the root causes. Only you have the experience of running the software, observing and recording evidence and drawing conclusions.  We can't do it.  I suspect you are going to have big problems because you have, for instance, not described what the CPU usage is while the app is 'frozen' - is it 0, 100% of a core, or 100% of more than one core?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you means by logging? How could I log the process related info under windows?

Comment: Oh - perfmon will show process/thread related stuff.  I meant app-level logging so that you can identify what happened just before the crash.

Comment: That's the problem I am having now, even if I attached a debugger I could only view the call stack after the crashing...Is it possible to view the call stack history through the debugger. If not could you suggest a app-level logging tool that could do it?

Comment: Why don't you just tell me more about the software? What are you trying to achieve and what issues do you see?

Comment: Unfortunately this thread is closed - which I personally find pretty stupid, since it is a very fundamental and important question - and by no means "too broad". So I can only post an answer here.

I usually catch deadlocks by a watchdog thread.
The watchdog thread checks, if the threads are still alive (for example by a frame counter), and if they are not (the frame counter has not changed for 60 seconds) it invokes a willful crash. The crash invokes a dump (eg. via DebugDiagnosticTool), and you can nicely evaluate the dump afterwards, since it also contains the locked mutexes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can run your program under MacOS/X, one useful thing to do when your program is in the deadlocked state is to bring up Activity Monitor, select your Process, and do a "Sample Process" or a "Run Spindump".  That will show you the current stack trace of every thread in your process -- most likely you will find two (or more) threads are blocked in a lock() call, and from examining the locations of those lock() calls you can figure out which mutexes are the ones causing the deadlock.  That can go a long way towards figuring out how the deadlock is occurring.

Alternatively, if you can build your program under Linux, you could use valgrind's [helgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html#hg-manual.lock-orders) tool to detect potential deadlocks.  There may be similar tools for other OS's, I'm not sure.

If not, then you'll need to analyze all of the sequences in which locks are acquired in your program.  For a small program, you can do this by eye -- go through all of the code paths and write down what locks are acquired, and in what order.  What you're particularly interested in is cases where a thread is holding more than one lock at a time -- if there is another thread that also holds those locks, AND the other thread did not acquire those locks in the same order as the first thread, that is a potential deadlock right there.  Cases where a thread acquires a single lock and then releases it (without acquiring any other locks in the meantime), on the other hand, are never a cause of a deadlock, so you can ignore them.

If your program is too large/complicated for a manual analysis to be possible, and you don't have an automated tool to examine lock-acquisition sequences, you can "roll your own" with a little bit of work.  What you'd want to do is search-and-replace all of your program's lock-commands with a wrapper function that prints out some debug info before acquiring the lock.  The wrapper function could look something like this:

```
#define my_lock(theMutex) my_lock_aux(__FILE__, __LINE__, theMutex)
void my_lock_aux(const char * file, int line, QMutex & theMutex)
{
   printf("Thread %i is about to lock mutex %p at [%s:%i]\n", (int)pthread_self(), &theMutex, file, line);
   theMutex.lock();
}
```

... and do something similar for your unlock() calls:

```
#define my_unlock(theMutex) my_unlock_aux(__FILE__, __LINE__, theMutex)
void my_unlock_aux(const char * file, int line, QMutex & theMutex)
{
  theMutex.unlock();
  printf("Thread %i unlocked mutex %p at [%s:%i]\n", (int)pthread_self(),  &theMutex, file, line);
}
```

Once you've got that done and compiling, you can run your program and it will print lots of output to stdout.  Redirect that to a file, give your program a bit of exercise (note:  you don't actually have to reproduce a deadlock, you just need to get a representative example of your program's behavior), and then quit your program.

Now you have a text file full of "Thread 1234 is about to lock mutex blah at [...]" and "Thread 31415 unlocked mutex blah at [...]" messages, and you can write a little program that parses that file to automatically determine the sets of mutexes each thread held simultaneously, and the order in which that thread acquired those mutexes.

Once that program has finished parsing the file, you can then have it print out all of the multiple-lock-acquisition-sequences it found, so that you can visually see where the inconsistent-orderings are; e.g. it might print out something like this:

```
 Thread 1234 acquired 4 locks simultaneously:
    -> Lock 0x1236782 was acquired at somefile.cpp:128
    -> Lock 0x2304890 was acquired at anotherfile.cpp:57
    -> Lock 0x0945820 was acquired at yetanotherfile.c:562
    -> Lock 0x2345824 was acquired at somefile.c:125

 Thread 4261 acquired 2 locks simultaneously:
    -> Lock 0x0945820 was acquired at yetanotherfile.c:562
    -> Lock 0x2304890 was acquired at anotherfile.cpp:57
```

... and then you'd note that Thread 4261 acquired its locks in a different order than Thread 1234 did, introducing a possible deadlock.  You'd then need to figure out how to modify your program so that the two threads acquire those mutexes in the same order... or better yet, modify it so that the threads don't have to hold multiple mutexes locked at the same time at all.

If you want to go a bit further you can even write a function that compares all of the sequences, and flags the ones whose orderings represent a potential deadlock.  If there are a large number of sequences, that can be more reliable than trying to detect them by eye.

FWIW, [here](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/test/deadlockfinder.cpp) is the source code of a program that I wrote to do the log-file parsing and analysis I described above; maybe it will be helpful as an example (or maybe it will just confuse you, in which case please ignore it).